Insights on why my answer was deleted without comments
I have recently added an answer (10k rep necessary to see it) to a question which I thought had a single, very unsatisfactory answer.
For some reason, my answer was deleted without explanation.
Could I get some insights about this deletion, and what should I do next time I want to contribute to this community?
Here is the answer:

Perhaps sidestepping a little the question, but Sklar's Theorem
states the general relation (assuming the densities exist)
$$f(x,y)=c(F_X(x),F_Y(y))f(x)f(y)$$
Where $c$ is the copula density
$$c(F_X(x),F_Y(y))=\frac{\partial^2 C(u,v)}{\partial u \partial v}, u=F_X(x), v=F_Y(y)$$
which encodes any interdependence (or lack of) between $X$ and $Y$
r.v.s.

The copula is the function relating the joint CDF and the marginal
CDFs.
$$F(x,y)=\Pr(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=C(F_X(x), F_Y(y))$$


Not that it can clarify anything, but https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/2156409

I really wonder why people are voting to delete without leaving a comment. That's not transparent.

This was brought up in the Ten fold chat

This answer looks fine to me. It is similar to the most upvoted answer there, and was actually posted first by almost a month.

I've been reading the policy on MathSE on low-quality questions, and it seems like my answer could be taken to be against the current policy. Could that be the reason for the deletion? The point of this post is mostly towards understanding what I did wrong, which might direct my future contributions to this site.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with the answer.  My guess, and it is just a guess, is that people think the question itself falls short of current standards.

Abuse of power.

Yes, the question is definitely low-quality as per today's standards. Your answer is not very different from the more recent one which has three up votes, but that user has a longer answer, so it goes over the independence case and leaves a link to Sklar's original paper, which is informative. So (i) avoid low-quality questions, even if old (ii) provide as much detail as possible in your answers. Note that the question and other answers have comments below them mentioning the low-quality nature of the question.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer If that is the reason for deletion, could you please add it as an answer?

I presented the 3rd vote to undelete, OP.

the reason being is that the answer of yours came before the one that was upvoted $3$ times and is not much different, less details but similar idea.

@Firebug I'm not completely convinced though, and Mike has another point. While what I'm saying will definitely help in the prevention of downvotes, if another person writes a better answer than you (easy to do here, but may not be easy elsewhere) then people may downvote for a reason like the person here. Not saying that I agree, but arguments do exist in its favour.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer what does downvoting have to do with it?

@Firebug One downvote is required to trigger deletion, bit users who delete vote are often likely to downvote so that even if the answer is not deleted early it becomes less likely to be read by others. Anyway the answer has been undeleted and voted up.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer I understand that, but the answer was not downvoted before deletion

@Firebug Oh yes, you're right. The answer was deleted from a low-quality review, and someone flagged it when it appeared in the first answers queue. But yes, whether it's prevent of downvotes or flagging as low-quality, the previous two points hold. I now wonder if Mike's point holds though : one shouldn't flag a post as low-quality because it's worse than another one, it pretty much has to be worse in and of itself for that. Your post isn't low-quality as far as I'm concerned, it's just worse than the best one. Ok, now I might think of writing an answer.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer My answer was posted and deleted almost one month prior to the newest answer posting

@Firebug Personally, the idea of deleting an answer because the question is of low quality makes no sense to me.  There is already a mechanism in place to close and then delete low quality questions.  This automatically results in the deletion of any posted answer.  So, what is the point of deleting the answer (only), but not deleting the (low quality) question?
